# Why we need to delete "PassengerID" in the titanic testing dataset

Tags: data-science

Hey guys I have a really quick question about the titanic kaggle data set. Here is the link:

```
    https://github.com/riederleeDEV/Titanic-kaggle- 
    competition/blob/master/titanic-solution.ipynb
    Notice that In[87] drop the "PassengerID" in the test data set
```

I mean why do we need to drop it?

Answer (score 0):

Because Passenger id doesn't add any value to determine the survival status of a passenger. 
If you plot passenger Ids with the survival status, you wont find any correlation between. 
From a common sense view, Its like a ticket number of any show/flight and its just a number nothing more than that.

Comment: Yes I totally understand this point. Thank you for your explaination!

Comment: @Rieder please upvote if you are okay with my answer